# boost::interprocess::named_mutex vs CreateMutex

Tags: c++, windows, mutex, boost-interprocess, single-instance

I want to switch from `CreatMutex` to `boost::interprocess::named_mutex` to limit my application to a single instance. Both methods works when the application runs and ends just fine. However, the lock is not released when the application crashes and using `boost::interprocess::named_mutex`. I could resolve that issue by using two name_mutex but I don't really understand the issue.

Why is the lock for `boost::interprocess::named_mutex` not released when the application crashes but it is release with `CreatMutex`? What's the difference?

---

```
boost::interprocess::named_mutex mutex(boost::interprocess::open_or_create, "my_mutex");
boost::interprocess::scoped_lock<boost::interprocess::named_mutex> lock(mutex, boost::interprocess::try_to_lock);
if(!lock) {
    return 1; //exit
}
//application may crash here.
boost::interprocess::named_mutex::remove("my_mutex");
return 1; //exit
```

Comment: do you remove the file used for the mutex?

Comment: @itwasntpete I use `boost::interprocess::named_mutex::remove`. But I don't know where the file is located in the file system.

Comment: do you remove it before using it?

Comment: @itwasntpete No, my goal is to have a single instance. Removing it will allow for multiple instances.

Comment: please post some code. how/where do you remove it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Caveat*: I've not spent much time with `boost::interprocess`, so this information is just from a quick inspection of the source. That said, I've used the Windows synchronisation API's a lot, so here goes...

---

The main difference between the two methods of interprocess synchronisation is how the object exists within the system.

With `boost::interprocess::named_mutex`, as well as a system-specific mutex, it looks like a synchronisation object is created as a file on the system.  The location of the file is based on Registry entries (see note 1) (at least in Boost 1.54.0)... it's *most likely* located under the Common Application Data folder (see note 2).  When the aplication crashes, this file is, in your case, not removed.  I'm not sure if this is by design... however in the case of an application crash, it's perhaps best not to mess with the file system, *just in case*.

Conversely, when you use `CreateMutex`, an object is created at the kernel mode, which for named mutexes can be accessed by several applications.  You get a handle to the Mutex by specifying the name when you create it, and you lose the handle when you call `CloseHandle` on it.  The mutex object is destroyed when there are no more handles referencing it.

The important part of this is in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411.aspx):

> **The system closes the handle automatically when the process terminates**. The mutex object is destroyed when its last handle has been closed.

This basically means that Windows will clean up after your application.

Note that if you don't perform a `ReleaseMutex`, and your application owns the mutex when it dies, then it's possible/likely that a waiting thread or process would see that the mutex had been abandoned (`WaitForSingleObject` returns `WAIT_ABANDONED`), and would gain ownership.

I apologise for not providing a solution, but I hope it answers your question about why the two systems act differently.

---

1. Just as an aside, using registry entries to get this information is horrible - it would be safer, and more future-proof, to use `SHGetKnownFolderPath`. But I digress.
2. Depending on your OS version, this could be `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\boost.interprocess` or `ProgramData\boost.interprocess`, or somewhere else entirely.

Comment: Is there any way to ensure a single application instance on Windows using boost (rather than Windows API)?

Comment: @joshuanapoli: No idea, it's something I tend not to do, as the negatives outweigh any reason to do it.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not trivial and the interprocess_mutex definitively the wrong way to do.

What you may could do is remove the mutex on termination, by providing a remover destructor and/or in a catch(...). But this is not guaranteed to work, since it won't be done if you terminate the process directly (from the OS). Also it could accidently remove the mutex while your application starts twice.

One approach is to safe the process-id (for example in a shared memory) on the first time your program starts and remove it when it stops. Everytime you start the application read and check if the id still in process, if not, start the program.

Comment: Doesn't boost provide any way to create a real mutex object?  (Using a file is wrong in so many ways.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I _think_ that it actually does both - it creates a mutex, and a "named sync" object, which is the file. A comment in the source for `windows_named_sync` states `Use a file to emulate POSIX lifetime semantics`. Still a horrible thing to do, mind.